# Issue Centering Text Vertically on Labels Using MAUI

Tags: label, maui, centering, absolutelayout

I'm using the following code to create and render a simple Label.  The layout is set to have the same height and width as the screen.

```
maincontent = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AbsoluteLayout
{
    BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
    HeightRequest = mainmescreenheight,
    IsEnabled = true,
    IsVisible = true,
    WidthRequest = mainmescreenwidth
};

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label newLabel = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label
{
    BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
    FontAttributes = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FontAttributes.Bold,
    FontFamily = "VerdanaBold",
    FontSize = 14,
    HorizontalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
    IsEnabled = true,
    IsVisible = true,
    MinimumHeightRequest = 300,
    MinimumWidthRequest = 640,
    Text = "Center of Label",
    TextColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFFFF"),
    VerticalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
    VerticalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center
};
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(newLabel, Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(newLabel, new Rect(0, 0, 640, 300));
maincontent.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

I want the text, in this case "Center of Label" to appear both vertically and horizontally centered.

Although the text is always horizontally centered, it always appears at the very top of the label as if VerticalTextAlignment and VerticalOptions were set to .Start rather than .Center.

How do I get the text to center vertically?  This is net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0.

Comment: Why did you set a MinimumHeightRequest in label? It just equals to the value set in SetLayoutFlags method. Remove MinimumHeightRequest property, and the text appears centered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

> I'm using the following code to create and render a simple Label. The layout is set to have the same height and width as the screen.

Your `AbsoluteLayout` setup is the problem and the Min Height/Width is unnecessary.

Below is how your code should look:

```
maincontent = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AbsoluteLayout
{
    BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
    HeightRequest = mainmescreenheight, 
    WidthRequest = mainmescreenwidth
};

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label newLabel = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label
{
    BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
    FontAttributes = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FontAttributes.Bold,
    FontFamily = "VerdanaBold",
    FontSize = 14,
    HorizontalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center,
    HorizontalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
    Text = "Center of Label",
    TextColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFFFF"),
    VerticalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
    VerticalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center
};
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(newLabel, Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(newLabel, new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1));
maincontent.Children.Add(newLabel);
```

Also, I have no clue why you have

> HeightRequest = mainmescreenheight

or

> WidthRequest = mainmescreenwidth

In your AbsoluteLayout.

AbsoluteLayout by default fits into its parent.

Comment: Thank you.  Although from your revised code I'm unable to determine how the label knows it is supposed to be 640 wide and 300 high.

Comment: Why do you want it to be 640/300 though?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Here is a demo I created,

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AbsoluteLayout maincontent = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.AbsoluteLayout
    {
        BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
        IsEnabled = true,
        IsVisible = true,
    };

    Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label newLabel = new Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label
    {
        BackgroundColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FF221E1F"),
        FontAttributes = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.FontAttributes.Bold,
        FontFamily = "VerdanaBold",
        FontSize = 14,
        HorizontalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
        IsEnabled = true,
        IsVisible = true,
        Text = "Center of Label",
        TextColor = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color.FromArgb("#FFFFFFFF"),
        VerticalTextAlignment = Microsoft.Maui.TextAlignment.Center,
        VerticalOptions = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.LayoutOptions.Center
    };
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(newLabel, Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(newLabel, new Rect(0.5, 0.5, 640, 300));
    maincontent.Children.Add(newLabel);

    Content = maincontent;
}
```

This is the effect, is this what you want?

[image]

---

Original Answer

> The HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions properties have no effect on children of an AbsoluteLayout.

So if you want to put the label vertically and horizontally centered, you should use AbsoluteLayoutFlags. Consider the following code:

```
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(newLabel, Microsoft.Maui.Layouts.AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(newLabel, new Rect(0.5,0.5, 640, 300));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What I want to do is center the text vertically inside the label.  By experimentation, the SetLayoutFlags must absolutely be None, and the rectangle must have the absolute coordinates.  Also, in the original code snippet above, assigning anything to HorizontalOptions or VerticalOptions is unnecessary, changes nothing, and these assignments have been removed.  These were just our attempts to get the text to center; they affect the positioning of the control and not the text within.  It looks like this is a bug and setting VerticalTextAlignment to Center is pointless.

Comment: Have you tried remove MinimumHeightRequest as FreakyAli said?

Comment: Yes.  Removing MinimumHeightRequest has no impact on centering text within a Label control.

Comment: I add some pieces of code and the effect, is this effect what you want?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with this.  The effect is what we are seeking.  However, we are using AbsoluteLayoutFlags.None so we can absolutely position the control on the screen.  We wish to vertically center text inside a control regardless of where that control is positioned on the screen.

Comment: UPDATE: I can confirm this issue exists when "Windows Machine" is selected as the target device.  It does not exist on the emulated device "Pixel 5 - API33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)".

Comment: Yes, android works fine. But when removing MinimumHeightRequest, the label text can be centered on Windows. It's weird that it doesn't work for you. What the .NET version do you use?

Comment: net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0

Comment: I use the same .NET as yours.